# Can I run a second server on a Virtual Machine on my original physical server, or do I need to run 2 Virtual Machines to have 2 servers?

Tags: sql-server, virtualisation, windows-server-2022

The company I work for has a File Share server running on an server that is running Windows Server 2022. Its a simple setup that just uses Workgroups rather than a domain controller. They use a CAD software called Microvellum that requires an SQL server to host all of their data. The Microvellum website recommends having a dedicated server for the SQL that is only used for Microvellum, no other applications.

I know that the recommended way to setup the new workflow would be to have 2 virtual machines, 1 running the file share (and probably a domain controller in the future) and another running the SQL server. But, am I able to keep the file share server on the original install of Windows Server, and run the SQL server on a Virtual Machine? I've never seen anyone just run a single virtual machine, so I'm unsure how it affects performance.

Answer (score 1):

> But, am I able to keep the file share server on the original install of Windows Server, and run the SQL server on a Virtual Machine?

I don't see why not, but I also don't know what the CAD software requires.

> I've never seen anyone just run a single virtual machine, so I'm unsure how it affects performance.

It's all dependent upon the resources given to it. It's the same physical hardware, just a different operating system environment. In extremely simple setups such as this, it's not necessarily a bad thing to have everything on the same machine if it eases deployment and administration. It's doubtful, with decent hardware, that you'd need to change this in the future for a small company, but if you did want to keep things separated then how it is configured will depend on the edition and version of SQL Server.